# How do I debug a process running on a different machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I have 3 machines:

1. Local machine
2. Linux build machine
3. Linux test machine

My process is to SSH into the build machine, do my development there, `make` the project which outputs binaries into a `release/` directory. Then I `rsync` my `release/` directory to the test machine, where I actually run the program.

I have to develop and build on the build machine due to horrible DL speeds to my local machine, downloading the full git repo is impossibly slow. I have to deploy and run on the test machine due to the way the test network environment is setup.

Is there any way to attach a debugger on the build machine to the process running on the test machine? Or am I relegated to `print` statements?

Edit:

I think this is a duplicate of [Is there a way to attach to a remote process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500126/)

Comment: Check this doc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gnat_ugn/Remote-Debugging-with-gdbserver.html#Remote-Debugging-with-gdbserver

Comment: you can run VSC remote, see the docs

Comment: Install gdb on the build machine?

Comment: Fun side note: some 20 years ago I had a similar remote debugging requirement, and without gdbserver, but it did have X. I totally hacked up an alternative. The arch was a service library loaded by a Lotus Domino server, in case you're wondering. On load, I (a) forked, (b) had the forked child exec an xterm that launched gdb using the parent process id as the attach-to pid, (c) specified my workstation IP (literally in another city) as the display target. As soon as the service came up, presto, an xterm appeared on my desktop running gdb interactive. Hideous, but worked, and killed the bug.